# What's the game in which the PCs themselves have character sheets?

Tags: history-of-gaming, product-identification, metagaming, fantasy

Inspired by [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/49104/metagaming-only-campaign-possible-if-so-how), I was reminded of a role-playing game solicited in a late 90s or early 00s [*Previews*](http://www.previewsworld.com/Home/1/1/71/940) (Diamond Distribution's monthly comic book and associated merchandise--including games--catalog). The game's setting was a traditional fantasy world wherein a series of books--reskinned by the game's authors to avoid infringement--falls from the sky. These books *also* describe a traditional fantasy world. The denizens of this fantasy world adopt the books as scripture and require all the setting's folks to have character sheets, which--either by magic or because the authorities say so--make interaction with the world different based on the sheet the denizen carries.

For example, at the actual, in-real-life gaming table sits Alex whose character in the game is a big burly warrior who's *character*'s character sheet says he's a halfling thief. Therefore, the world interacts with Alex's character as if he were a halfling thief despite him being a big burly fighter.

I remember pre-ordering it and being disappointed the game was cancelled a few months before its release, never to be resolicited. I don't remember the game system. I don't remember the publisher. I don't even know if I've the *premise* exactly correct (hey, it was 1 paragraph in a 400-page catalog, like, 10 years ago).

What is this game's name? Was it ever released?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The game was called **FRUP**. It was never released (one of the casualties of the collapse of Guardians of Order), but the story of it — and [the preview of the game](https://web.archive.org/web/20100831003246/http://www.whatisfrup.com/?page_id=7) from 1995 — was available at WhatIsFRUP.com. But that site is no longer extant; the text is available [from the Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20100829110607/http://www.whatisfrup.com/). It's in first person — as written by James Wallis. According to Mr. Wallis, he still has an interest in it, although [he's changed the name to "DANDY."](https://forum.rpg.net/index.php?threads/rpgs-that-were-a-flash-in-the-pan.911238/page-38#post-24939726)

Comment: Very cool. That *should* be it (I mean, what *else* could it be?), but I'll hold off for a day in case there's more to it. I didn't see mention of Guardians of Order in there, though. Hogshead, yes, but not GOO. Is there something I'm missing? (I'm also going to have to use one of the suggested mechanics from one of the comments on that page in a game though: "Throw a gerbil, and if it runs off the table you fail." One of my players actually *has* gerbils.)

Comment: There's a reference to the "Magnum Opus" program, where GOO was going to serve as publisher for independent, already developed RPGs that needed a line toward print publishing and access to distribution. GoO was going to be the home of Hogshead Publishing products like Nobilis. The disposition of those books, and the money that came from selling them, was a matter of some acrimony later on.

Comment: Not only was it never published, but according to *Designers & Dragons: The 90s* (p. 223) the system design notes were actually destroyed after a license dispute. Obliterated games always make me sad. :(

Comment: @GMJoe Thanks! I've replaced it with the Wayback Machine link — I don't know if it's right to put the full text in, but you can read it.